# Script prints the name of the variable instead of its value

Tags: javascript

I'm using this script that takes an url and modifies it. It stores the new URL in a variable called #url and then it sets that variable as the href of a link.

It's changing the HREF however instead of printing the URL it's creating a link to the name of the variable: #url

This is the script:

```
    if(url.match(/http:\/\//))
    {
    url = url.substring(7);
    }
    if(url.match(/^www\./))
    {
    url = url.substring(4);
    }
    url = "www.chusmix.com/tests/?ref=" + url;
    $("#output").html(url);
    $("#url").val(url).focus().select();
    var yourElement = document.getElementById('test');
 yourElement.setAttribute('href', '#url');
```

I'm trying to make it work in JSFiddle, I just tried chaning the quotes but didn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lisandro/JKxRg/4/

Thanks for any help

Comment: try removing your single quotes.  the quotes are making it a string and not a call to the var.

Comment: I just tried without them on the variable and without them and with double  quotes and neither did work =S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes and no need to update the val if you going to change the attribute later.

```
 yourElement.setAttribute('href', url);
```

Answer (score 0):

yourElement.setAttribute('href', '#url');

'#url'?

You're printing a literal, so why are you surprised when you see a literal. jhanifen has given you the correct answer.

Comment: I have no idea how to use js it's my first site using it that's why. not mad. just telling